# How to change vertices on a circle?

Tags: vertices

Just a quick little question, in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY

At around 41:20 he someone makes it so he can edit the vertices on the circle, but he never says what button he hits to do it, and I've been googling and I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's in edit mode, try pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button to enter it.

By the way, I'd absolutely recommend you checking out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrgQj91MOVfjTShOMRY8TLmkJ7OFr7bj6), especially the first 2-3 lessons. It goes in detail about Blender UI and all its menus and submenus.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to what he does at 41:02 (not 41:20), just after adding a cìrcle, at the bottom of the toolbox panel (left to the 3d view, activate with <kbd>T</kbd>, there is a slider which is set at the default circle vertices count, but **before exiting edit mode**, you can edit it: he changes it to 200, in the video.

[image]

Comment: I know that, but at 41:20 the circle is a solid orange, then he presses a button and the vertices actually appear along the circle and he can move them, what is that button?

Comment: As other said that is simply edit mode.. tab key.